# Define C# class outside of any namespace

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

Is it possible to define a **class** (not interface) outside of any namespace?

Comment: Yeah, it just ends up in the global namespace.

Comment: You can, but why would you want to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ran a test and yes you can. Here's my code built off of a Console App:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace With_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("This will output something: ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            some.Print();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class some
{
    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("something");
    }
}
```

Yes, you can define a class outside of a namespace. Per juharr it ends up in the default global namespace.

Comment: Actually it will end up in the default global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Okay, thank you all. Does the global namespace called "Global" or it has its own name?

Comment: Some reading material: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx in the example above, looks like it would be under the "some" namespace? I could've glanced over that wrong.